# Sensors in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I wanna create an app by using acceleration sensor.But I don't know how can I test it in emulator?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the Android emulators support the acceleration sensor nicely by default.

However, you can download [SensorSimulator](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator) from Google, which lets you give the Android emulator simulated sensor data with the mouse. Just follow the instructions on the website and you should be good to go.

**Update (4/5/2016):**

As Maks kindly pointed out, OpenIntents SensorSimulator has moved here: http://github.com/openintents/sensorsimulator

Additionally, some hardware emulation is now supported: http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation

Comment: i tried but i can't open .jar file! How can i open it? Which program?

Comment: Follow the instructions on the page!

Comment: Bringing this up to date, there is some sensor hardware emulation using a USB connected android device with http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation while the OpenIntents SensorSimulator is now at https://github.com/openintents/sensorsimulator