# Cant find the default gyroscope on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, gyroscope

I'm trying to wrap my head around sensors in android using the gyroscope.. (Im new to this if you haven't gathered yet..)

When I run the app on the built in android emulator I keep getting told the device doesn't have a gyroscope.

```
gyroscopeSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

    if (gyroscopeSensor == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device has no gyroscope...", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
```

I've created a new virtual device and checked it had a gyroscope, but still no dice..

Please don't let this be a stupid error. I was doing so well!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677128/sensors-in-android-emulator

Comment: So, the 'virtual sensors' in the extended control are just for show?

Comment: You can get the sensor list to see which sensors your emulator supports. `List<Sensor> deviceSensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it..

This was due to running an API >23

Comment: Could you explain it on more details. How did you resolve it?

Comment: Just create a new device in the ADV with a API of 23 or less.